# What are all the argument prefixes?

Tags: ruby

I just received the following warning from my syntax checker:

`'&' interpreted as argument prefix`

The warning came in response to something like `array.all? &:blank?` where parenthesis would have been nice.

This got me thinking, what other argument prefixes are there? Searching on Google yields mostly results for this particular error, but I'd like a list of the argument prefixes and what they all do.

Comment: The argument prefixes have changed slightly since the duplicate question was asked. There is now a double-asterick for hash/keyword arguments (e.g. `def a(**kwargs)`), asterick prefixes work in assignments (e.g. `a, *b = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`)